# Slow service response Times : Java SecureRandom & /dev/random

Tags: java, tomcat, random, aes, strace

I am trying to debug a few slow responses served by an app deployed on Tomcat.
Right now I am focussing on `SecureRandom` and `/dev/random` (some of the other probable causes have been investigated and ruled out).
The pattern is as follows:

- The first call takes exactly **30.0**xy seconds after Tomcat restart (even if the request arrives 4 minutes after the Startup)
- Later, some calls take exactly **15.0**pq seconds (there was no specific pattern that I could establish, *pq* being the time approximate time taken in TP99)

The service call involves encryption and decryption (*AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding*).

*Is it possible that SecureRandom init/repopulating is leading to this?*

(Although, there is a log written in catalina.log that says `"Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [28,760] milliseconds."`)

Also, in order to check whether `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` is being used, I used the test from [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/40634/20446). To my surprise, I didn't see reads from either of them unlike the way it happens in the linked question.
These are the last few lines from the `strace` log:

```
3561  lstat("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=258525, ...}) = 0
3561  open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar", O_RDONLY) = 6
3561  stat("/dev/random", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 8), ...}) = 0
3561  stat("/dev/urandom", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
3561  open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY)     = 7
3561  open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)    = 8
3561  unlink("/tmp/hsperfdata_xxxx/3560") = 0
```

What is then being used for seeding SecureRandom?

fyi, *java -version*

```
java version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.4) (rhel-7.1.13.4.el6_5-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You could try a small application that creates a new random gen (using `new SecureRandom`) and then read some bytes from it, see if that reads from `urandom`. Make sure you target the same Java runtime though, and check if the `java.security.egd` property is not set using `java -D` for Tomcat.

Comment: I did run a sample program (code taken from the question on the link). It read from neither of /dev/random nor /dev/urandom as indicated in the strace logs attached to the question.

Comment: Could you also check `jre/lib/security/java.security` and check how `securerandom.source` is defined?

Comment: Thanks @owlstead. It is /dev/urandom.

Comment: Could you try `/dev/./urandom` in there and see what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not check your OpenJDK concrete version, but I could check [jdk6-b33](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/34f17b5fe0dc).

[SecureRandom](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/493340f21025/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java) uses [SeedGenerator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/493340f21025/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SeedGenerator.java) to get the seed bytes

```
public byte[] engineGenerateSeed(int numBytes) {
    byte[] b = new byte[numBytes];
    SeedGenerator.generateSeed(b);
    return b;
}
```

SeedGenerator gets the `seedSource` (String) from [SunEntries](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/SunEntries.java)

```
String egdSource = SunEntries.getSeedSource();
```

`SunEntries` tries to get the source from the system property `java.security.egd` first, if is not found then tries to get the property `securerandom.source` from the `java.security` properties file, if the property is not found returns a blank string.

```
// name of the *System* property, takes precedence over PROP_RNDSOURCE
private final static String PROP_EGD = "java.security.egd";
// name of the *Security* property
private final static String PROP_RNDSOURCE = "securerandom.source";

final static String URL_DEV_RANDOM = "file:/dev/random";
final static String URL_DEV_URANDOM = "file:/dev/urandom";

private static final String seedSource;

static {
    seedSource = AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new PrivilegedAction<String>() {

        public String run() {
            String egdSource = System.getProperty(PROP_EGD, "");
            if (egdSource.length() != 0) {
                return egdSource;
            }
            egdSource = Security.getProperty(PROP_RNDSOURCE);
            if (egdSource == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return egdSource;
        }
    });
}
```

the `SeedGenerator` check this value to initialize the instance

```
// Static instance is created at link time
private static SeedGenerator instance;

private static final Debug debug = Debug.getInstance("provider");

final static String URL_DEV_RANDOM = SunEntries.URL_DEV_RANDOM;
final static String URL_DEV_URANDOM = SunEntries.URL_DEV_URANDOM;

// Static initializer to hook in selected or best performing generator
static {
    String egdSource = SunEntries.getSeedSource();

    // Try the URL specifying the source
    // e.g. file:/dev/random
    //
    // The URL file:/dev/random or file:/dev/urandom is used to indicate
    // the SeedGenerator using OS support, if available.
    // On Windows, the causes MS CryptoAPI to be used.
    // On Solaris and Linux, this is the identical to using
    // URLSeedGenerator to read from /dev/random

    if (egdSource.equals(URL_DEV_RANDOM) || egdSource.equals(URL_DEV_URANDOM)) {
        try {
            instance = new NativeSeedGenerator();
            if (debug != null) {
                debug.println("Using operating system seed generator");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (debug != null) {
                debug.println("Failed to use operating system seed "
                              + "generator: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    } else if (egdSource.length() != 0) {
        try {
            instance = new URLSeedGenerator(egdSource);
            if (debug != null) {
                debug.println("Using URL seed generator reading from "
                              + egdSource);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (debug != null)
                debug.println("Failed to create seed generator with "
                              + egdSource + ": " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    // Fall back to ThreadedSeedGenerator
    if (instance == null) {
        if (debug != null) {
            debug.println("Using default threaded seed generator");
        }
        instance = new ThreadedSeedGenerator();
    }
}
```

if the source is

```
final static String URL_DEV_RANDOM = "file:/dev/random";
```

or

```
final static String URL_DEV_URANDOM = "file:/dev/urandom"
```

uses the `NativeSeedGenerator`, on Windows tries to use the native `CryptoAPI` on Linux the class simply extends the `SeedGenerator.URLSeedGenerator`

```
package sun.security.provider;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Native seed generator for Unix systems. Inherit everything from
 * URLSeedGenerator.
 *
 */
class NativeSeedGenerator extends SeedGenerator.URLSeedGenerator {

    NativeSeedGenerator() throws IOException {
        super();
    }

}
```

and call to the superclass constructor who loads `/dev/random` by default

```
URLSeedGenerator() throws IOException {
    this(SeedGenerator.URL_DEV_RANDOM);
}
```

so, OpenJDK uses `/dev/random` by default until you do not set another value in the system property `java.security.egd` or in the property `securerandom.source` of security properties file.

If you want to see the read results using `strace` you can change the command line and add the `trace=open,read` expression

```
sudo strace -o a.strace -f -e trace=open,read java class
```

the you can see something like this (I did the test with Oracle JDK 6)

```
13225 open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY)     = 8
13225 read(8, "@", 1)                   = 1
13225 read(3, "PK\3\4\n\0\0\0\0\0RyzB\36\320\267\325u\4\0\0u\4\0\0 \0\0\0", 30) = 30
....
....
```

The Tomcat Wiki section for faster startup suggest using a non-blocking entropy source like /dev/urandom if you are experiencing delays during startup

More info: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the `read` traces, I confirm that the `\dev\urandom` is being used in this JVM. There is no egd override and  securerandom.source is also `\dev\urandom`. So, this rules out the possibility of SecureRandom as the cause and I'll have to look at other possible causes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not SecureRandom per se but that /dev/random blocks if it doesn't have enough data. You can use urandom instead but that might not be a good idea if you need cryptographically strong random seeds. 
On headless Linux systems you can install the haveged daemon. This keeps /dev/random topped up with enough data so that calls don't have to wait for the required entropy to be generated. 
I've done this on a Debian Aws instance and watched SecureRandom generateBytes calls drop from 25 seconds to sub millisecond (Openjdk 1.7 something, can't remember specifically what version).